# how to send mail in inbox using mail function

Tags: php

I am trying to send mail using mail function but it's always sent in spam folder and this message coming via @gator4120.hostgator.com

```
<?php
$subject = "Registration completed !!!! ";
$from= "From: admin@xxxx.com\n";
$message ="Dear ".$varfname.",\n";
$message = $message."\r\nCongratulations! \n";
$message = $message."You are now a member of B2B Portal.\n";
$message = $message."Your profile is under screening and will be activated within next 24 hrs.\n ";
$header .= "Reply-To: admin <$from>\r\n";
$header .= "Return-Path: admin <$from>\r\n";
$header .= "From: admin <$from>\r\n";
$header .= "Organization: The organization\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n";
if ( mail("webpixeltest@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $header)) {
echo "The email has been sent!";
} else {
echo "The email has failed!";
}
?>
```

Comment: if ti goes to spam its because the email server decides it's a spam, you cannot do much about it as a sender, except from using more reliable domains, and making messages less suspicious also warning customers it may happen. It's not something you can decide on, its on client's side. For the second part you'd need to provide more data, but notice that you do not pass your from variable to the mail at all, also its incorrect format.

Comment: is there any process to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host site your are using is hostgator to host your site. `mail()` is simply a built-in function that deliver mail to the local SMA (e.g. sendmail), from that point on it's depend on your machine's configuration. Here the configuration is set to `gator4120.hostgator.com` as the mail server, which is also used by many other using hostgator. Hence other using the mail sever to send emails might have been marked as spam, so naturally your email is also getting marked as spam. Solution for this is to user a different mail server like MailChimp [link](http://mailchimp.com/)

Try using

1. [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)
2. [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)

Comment: I'd also check if the from header format is actually correct,

Comment: i think because of server getting mail in spam box is it correct ?

Comment: yes, because others have marked the email received as spam. Which are not sent by you but by others who have used the same mail server. In gmail if one marks the email as spam it is reportedly considered as spam based on the mail server or email-id.

Comment: @shameem : i did try phpmailer and it's work thanx a lot